# Configuring a Linux Forwarding Engine

Tags: linux, networking, interface

I am trying to configure my Debian machine to simply forward all ingoing network packets on interface eth0 to eth1.
My hardware setup is the following:

**Sender Machine A (eth0)   ----> (eth0) Forward Machine B (eth1)  ---->  (eth0) Receiver Machine C**

Machine A simply generates different kinds of network packets (UDP, TCP, ICMP) using a raw socket and sends them over interface eth0, which is directly connected to the eth0 interface of Machine B.

Now, I want Machine B to simply forward each incoming packet, which it receives on eth0, to eth1, regardless of destination IP address, so that Machine C will finally receive those packets on its interface eth0.
The reason why I want to do this is an experiment in university.

However, although the default gateway on Machine B is set to the IP of Machine C, packets are not forwarded.
Interestingly, a direct ping from Machine A to Machine C works (routes are set up correctly).
Also, /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward is set to 1, and interface eth0 (the "receiving" interface on Machine B, is set to promiscuous mode, so that destination MAC addresses should not be a problem.

Does anybody have an idea, why this does not work?
Interestingly, if Machine B runs FreeBSD instead of Debian, it works just fine ...

Some Details:

- Machine B is a Raspberry Pi 2, with the second interface being a USB Ethernet adapter
- All sent packets are IPv4

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I wonder if you know this person? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236123/problem-with-forwarding-arbitrary-packets-on-debian